# Is there a cyclic dependency here?

Tags: c++, class, vector, g++

Below I have reproduced a simplified version of a part of my code that gives error when compiling.

**testing.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Beta.h"
#include "../Alpha.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

**Alpha.h**

```
#include <vector>

class Alpha
{
    public:

        typedef struct _info{
            int  k;
        } info;

        friend class Beta;
};
```

**Beta.h**

```
   #include <vector>
    
        class Alpha;
        
        class Beta
        {
            public:
            std::vector <Alpha::info*> vecInfo;
        };
```

When I run `g++ testing.cpp` I get below error message

> In file included from testing.cpp:10:0: ../Beta.h:8:15: error:
>
> incomplete type ‘Alpha’ used in nested name specifier ../Beta.h:8:15:
>
> error: incomplete type ‘Alpha’ used in nested name specifier
>
> ../Beta.h:8:27: error: template argument 1 is invalid ../Beta.h:8:27:
>
> error: template argument 2 is invalid

I can see from the forum threads that the first error is because of some kind of cyclic dependency ([Error: incomplete type used in nested name specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572483/error-incomplete-type-used-in-nested-name-specifier-g)). I am unable to see similarity between my code and their code. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: That's not a cyclic dependency. It simply means that you can't refer to `Alpha::info*` because that is not declared anywhere before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `Alpha.h` in `Beta.h`, because the full class definition is needed to have access to `Alpha::info`. This will not create a cyclic dependency because `Alpha.h` does not include `Beta.h`.

```
// don't forget the include guards!
#ifndef BETA_H_
#define BETA_H_

#include <vector>
#include "../Alpha.h"

class Beta
{
    public:
    std::vector <Alpha::info*> vecInfo;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what was wrong in my code initially? Why doesn't it understand when I write `class Alpha`? Where can I learn more about this particular issue? I don't know the technical term for this.

Comment: @user13107 a forward declaration is just saying "there is a class with this name Alpha or whatever, and we know nothing about it". When you say something like "Alpha::info" in your code, that code needs access to the full definition of the `Alpha` class. Otherwise it has no way of knowing abour `Alpha::info`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a circular dependency.  `Beta.h` just needs to `#include "Alpha.h"` instead of forward-declaring `class Alpha;`.

Comment: But then Alpha.h would have to forward-declare `Beta` so you can make it a friend of `Alpha`, no?

Comment: No, you can declare a `friend` class that's never been declared before.  If you want to declare `class Beta;` that might make it a little clearer, sure.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives a different error when I replace `class Alpha;` with `#include Alpha.h` `In file included from testing.cpp:11:0:
../Alpha.h:3:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Alpha’
../Alpha.h:3:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Alpha’`

Comment: That sounds like you are missing your include guards.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @user13107 You are probably missing include guards. See my answer.